# How to get all the videos link from a youtube playlist .

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube-api

i am using zend framework for retrieving youtube video information ,

I need a way To get all the video links inside a playlist, the playlist Id is known .

is there any method for retrieving the above information ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the YouTube Data API:

```
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
$feedUrl = $playlistEntry->getPlaylistVideoFeedUrl();
$playlistVideoFeed = $yt->getPlaylistVideoFeed($feedUrl);
```

You'll need to authenticate if it's a private playlist, but not if it's public.

Read more on the relevant [Zend Framework Manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.youtube.html#zend.gdata.youtube.playlists) and [Google Reference Guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#Playlist_feed) pages.